# Is it possible to define GUI elements in XML instead of Json in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I'm starting out with ExtJS, and I found it hard to write the Json for all the GUI elements, and going back and forth between the IDE and online documentation to figure things out. And I thought, it would have been much easier if there were an alternate XML format with a schema file containing all the documentation. Does ExtJS have such a format? Maybe a third party tool or extension?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at [Ext TLD](http://www.exttld.com/) which is about as close as you'll get without building your own interpreter.